# Another darn Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I know there's enough of these questions around, but I've looked through *several* of them and none of the recommendations have worked for me.

Here is my JS: http://pastebin.com/gUbtB2WP

Error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

The line is    `WPIS_Configuration.init();` which for all intents and purposes, I've deleted the line entirely (and the line before/after) and re-written it by hand.

Sublime usually gives you a visual indication, which I've included below:

[image: Sublime screenshot]

So - I'm utterly lost and frustrated at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you may be missing a closing bracket `}` before the call to `WPIS_Configuration.init();`

Comment: does that line in the `setInterval` callback continue? it ends with `.find(`, which would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never close the JSON, before WPIS_Configuration.init();, add "}".

Comment: Damn *shakes head*. I'll accept this as soon as it lets me. Appreciate it, thanks for humoring me :)

Comment: There's no JSON here... It's an object literal.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the object literal that starts here:

```
var WPIS_Configuration = {
```

The parser expects another identifier in the object, not code.

Comment: JNo was first, but you did correct clarify his answer, appreciate it!